# What does an “X” on the top of a folder mean? Image shown

Tags: macos

I was transferring data from my Windows USB flash drive to my new MacBook Pro. Apparently one of the folders copied now looks like this:

[image]

What does this mean? I would think that this displayed the copy progress however the folder has remained like this for a while now.

Comment: yep USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s the “how much has been copied” icon and so far, there’s not much by the look of it. Though it can get stuck on occasion.

Restarting Finder or rebooting—if you’re sure it really has finished—can clear it.

Comment: Yeah i took the flash out but this icon is still there. I pasted everything in the folder again but the icon is till there

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was right clicking on the folder and then choosing `Get Info`. That removed the 'x' and the progress bar. I think this is a bug in OS X El Capitan.